# ArcPy SearchCursor Error: "An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly"

Tags: arcpy, cursor, feature-class

Using ArcPy, I'm trying to use a search cursor on a point feature class to populate a list.

```py
import os, arcpy

# make feature layer in memory
lyr_acq = "lyr_acq"
arcpy.env.workspace = PROJECT_GDB 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('ORR_Test', lyr_acq)

# define fields to capture in cursor
name_field = "Acquisition_Name"
state_field = "State"
status_field = "Status"
type_field = "Business_Type"

lastEdit_field = "last_edited_date"
lastEditUser_field = "last_edited_user"

return_acqList = [] # populate list w/ cursor

expression = u' {0} = "Open" AND {1} >= "{2}" AND {3} = "domain\SVC_AGOLtoGIS" '.format(
                                                arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr_acq, status_field), 
                                                arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr_acq, lastEdit_field), 
                                                DATETIME_YESTERDAY_DATE, # not shown - used datetime module
                                                arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr_acq, lastEditUser_field)) #3
print(f'Search Expression:\n\t {expression}')

cursor_fields = [name_field, status_field, state_field, type_field]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr_acq, cursor_fields , where_clause = expression) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0]) # test
        return_acqList.append([row[0], row[3], row[-3]])
```

Returns the error below.

```py
Search Expression:
      "Status" = "Open" AND "last_edited_date" >= "2022-02-07" AND "last_edited_user" = "domain\SVC_AGOLtoGIS" 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-14e1fd929d54> in <module>
     36 
     37 with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr_acq, cursor_fields , where_clause = expression) as cursor:
---> 38     for row in cursor:
     39         print(row[0]) # test
     40         return_acqList.append([row[0], row[3], row[-3]])

RuntimeError: An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly. [lyr_acq]
```

I also tried checking all of the fields in `cursor_fields`  and they all are actual field names in the layer.

I am trying this query on a point feature class in a file geodatabase (`PROJECT_GDB`). I also tried it stored within a enterprise geodatabase (SDE).

Comment: `domain\SVC_AGOLtoGIS` isn't a field name.  What does `arcpy.ListFields` report on `lyr_acq`, e.g., `print(str([fld.name for fld in arcpy.ListFields(lyr_acq)]))` ?

Comment: @Vince - correct, part of the query is `"last_edited_user" = "domain\SVC_AGOLtoGIS"`. I've verified all strings in `cursor_fields` are in the layer using `arcpy.ListFields`. I can print them all

Comment: This was the point of @user2856 -- You cannot legally use double-quotes to refer to a string literal; only single-quotes (&APOS;) can be used to delimit strings, or dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression uses double quotes for the string values in the where clause. Use single quotes. I've swapped the outer string quotes so you don't need to escape embedded single quotes in the example below..

```
expression = r"{0} = 'Open' AND {1} >= date '{2}' AND {3} = 'domain\SVC_AGOLtoGIS'".format(
    arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr_acq, status_field), 
    arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr_acq, lastEdit_field), 
    DATETIME_YESTERDAY_DATE, # not shown - used datetime module
    arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(lyr_acq, lastEditUser_field))  # 3
```

Note I used a raw string `r"etc..."` because a backslash is an escape charater in Python so your  `'domain\SVC_AGOLtoGIS'` may have turned into `'domain VC_AGOLtoGIS'` (`\s` a space, but can't remember if `\S` is equivalent). If you need to use a `u"etc..."` string, escape all backslashes, e.g. `u"etc...  AND {3} = 'domain\\SVC_AGOLtoGIS'`

Comment: When rewriting the expression with double quotes - I get the error `An invalid SQL statement was used.` I tried using both raw (w/ backslash escaped) and unicode strings

Comment: When asking questions relating to databases, it's very important to specify exactly what type of database you are referring to.  Please edit your question to specify what "`PROJECT_GDB`" is.

Comment: @champezius your `"last_edited_date" >= DATETIME_YESTERDAY_DATE` is invalid sql and is unrelated to the issue in your question. It's also unanswerable as you didn't specify what "PROJECT_GDB" is or include how you derived DATETIME_YESTERDAY_DATE.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm#GUID-85C03D85-F4A5-48FC-8E8C-3F79919430DB

Comment: removing double quotes on the strings that were not fields (within the expression) resolved this issue